# Is there an English word for looking contemplatively at water?

Tags: single-word-requests

A friend of mine swears that he saw this word for **looking contemplatively at water** once.

However, I have been unable to find it, and as this activity is a favourite pastime of mine, I would like to see if it actually exists. It could very well be an extinct or old English word.

I am looking for it specifically to name a sailboat, which is why I am looking for a single word.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage and thank you for your question. What exactly are the quotation marks around *word* supposed to tell us? I can only guess that you may not necessarily be looking for a single word. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: I mean, I think *reflecting* is perfect on many levels.

Comment: Maybe _wetitation_?

Comment: Untranslatable from *what* to *what*? Is it an English word that wasn't translatable to French? Or a Malay word that isn't translatable to English? (in which case, as it isn't translatable, we can't help you)

Comment: I mean one of those words that is so specific it can't be translated accurately. For instance in Dutch there is a word gezellig that can't be translated into English. Perhaps I am not explaining myself correctly and will take that out of the description.

Comment: @user211783 What Andy meant is if you tell us what language your friend says this word exists in, and ideally what the word is, itself, that will give us hints which will help us further our research and maybe identify the English equivalent.

Comment: It's a pity _watergaze_ isn't a "real word" in the same way that _stargaze_ is; otherwise, I'd be leaving this as an answer instead of a comment. (_Watergaze_ could still be used as a name for a sailboat, though.)

Comment: “Immersed [in Thought]” could work for a submarine.

Comment: 'Watercourse-way', one path of the tao; see Alan Watt's last work.

Comment: Why can't *gezellig* be translated into English?

Answer (score -2):

Well, why not use *contemplatively*?

> She sat at the edge of the lake, *contemplatively*, reflecting upon the situation she found herself in.

Or inspired by *lecanoscopy*:

> She sat at the edge of the lake, *lecanoscopically*, reflecting upon the situation she found herself in.

Or by *lecanomancy*:

> She sat at the edge of the lake, *lecanomancically*, reflecting upon the situation she found herself in.

Or by *hydromancy*:

> She sat at the edge of the lake, *hydromancically*, reflecting upon the situation she found herself in.

Comment: I am looking specifically for this word, as I hope to use it as the name of a boat. The sentence was only to illuminate, but yes, contemplatively in this context would be perfect.

Comment: Because it doesn't mean "looking at water"?

Comment: I have found this one: lecanoscopy staring at pool of water as means of self-hypnosis

Comment: I've added lecanoscopy, lecanomancy and hydromancy inspired versions.